# Find $xyz$ if $x-\frac{1}{x}=y$, and $y-\frac{1}{y}=z$, and $z-\frac{1}{z}=x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If 
$$x-\frac{1}{x}=y, \qquad y-\frac{1}{y}=z, \qquad z-\frac{1}{z}=x$$ 
find the value of $xyz$.

This is how far I proceeded:
$x+y+z=z-1/z+x-1/x+y-1/y=>1/x+1/y+1/z=0
=>xy+yz+zx=0$
Also from question,
$x^2-1=xy,y^2-1=yz,z^2-1=zx$.
Adding $x^2+y^2+z^2-3=xy+yz+zx=0 =>x^2+y^2+z^2=3$  .
I am stuck here please help.
[This image gives some hint, but I am unable to understand it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DEJo.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with *learning*, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: I have updated my approach to question.

Comment: Which part of the solution do you not understand?

Comment: Where it says 'add all'. How did we get the zero first?

Comment: You seemed to have entered the wrong equation. Signs are negative; you entered positive.

Comment: Oh, that explains why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given: $x-\frac1x=y,y-\frac1y=z,z-\frac1z=x$, you found correctly:
$$x-\frac1x+y-\frac1y+z-\frac1z=y+z+x \Rightarrow \frac1x+\frac1y+\frac1z=0 \Rightarrow xy+yz+zx=0 \ \ (1)\\
x^2-1+y^2-1+z^2-1=xy+yz+zx \Rightarrow x^2+y^2+z^2=3 \ \ (2)$$
Square each and add them all:
$$x^2+\frac1{x^2}-2+y^2+\frac1{y^2}-2+z^2+\frac1{z^2}-2=y^2+z^2+x^2 \Rightarrow \frac1{x^2}+\frac1{y^2}+\frac1{z^2}=6 \Rightarrow \\
x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2=6x^2y^2z^2 \ \ (3)$$
Square $(1)$:
$$\underbrace{x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2}_{6x^2y^2z^2}+2xyz(x+y+z)=0 \Rightarrow x+y+z=-3xyz \ \ (4)$$
Square $(4)$:
$$\underbrace{x^2+y^2+z^2}_{3}+2(\underbrace{xy+yz+zx}_{0})=9x^2y^2z^2 \Rightarrow 3=9x^2y^2z^2 \Rightarrow xyz=\pm \frac1{\sqrt{3}}.$$

Comment: That was brilliant. Thanks a lot!

Comment: But I doubt if the solution provided in the image link is correct.

Comment: The referenced solution uses different approach to find $(4)$, other than that the two solutions are equivalent.

Comment: That's OK but how did we get 0 after 'add all' step?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: By the equation #(3) we get in #(1)
$$z-1/z-\frac{1}{z-\frac{1}{z}}=y$$
and with $z=y-\frac{1}{y}$ we get
$$3y^6-9y^4+6y^2-1=0$$
Multiplying all terms together gives
$$x^2(1-z^2)+y^2(1-z^2)+z^2(1-y^2)=0$$
substituting
$$xy=x^2-1$$
$$yz=y^2-1$$
$$xz=z^2-1$$
so we get
$$xyz(x+y+z)=0$$

Comment: Does it mean that xyz=0?

Comment: $x,y,z$ are the denominators, so $xyz\neq 0$

Comment: Neither xyz nor x+y+z is zero. So?

Comment: Now i have got with computer $${\frac {\sqrt {3}+i}{3+i\sqrt {3}}}$$. Are you sure that there is no typo?

Comment: According to my calculations it must be $x+y+z=0$

Comment: Applying (x+y+z)^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+yz+zx)=3+2*0=3=>x+y+z= +-sqrt3

Comment: Using Vieta's formulas, fixing $a=1$ we get the cubics: $x^3 - \sqrt{3}x^2 + 3x - xyz = 0$ or $x^3 + \sqrt{3}x^2 + 3x - xyz = 0$.

Comment: From your degree-six polynomial, $x^2y^2z^2=1/3$

Answer (score 0):

Note that adding up the three equations gives you:

$$x+y+z =x+y+z - \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y} - \frac{1}{z}$$

, so $$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{z} = 0$$

Try it from there

Comment: I tried uptil here. Unable to proceed further.

Comment: What about replacing $1/x = -1/y - 1/z$ and $x=\frac{-1}{1/y + 1/z}$ in all equations, then solve for $y$ and $z$? Does this lead to anything easily computable?

Comment: David, this doesn't help.

Comment: @ShubhamKumarVerma The other answer found $x+y+z=0$, so we may be a step closer to solving

Comment: No, x+y+z isn't zero.

Answer (score 0):

Eliminating $x$ and $z$ between the equations we obtain:
$$3y^6-9y^4+6y^2-1=0.$$

By symmetry we know that $x$ and $z$ must also satisfy this equation. Hence $x^2$, $y^2$ and $z^2$ are roots of $$3y^3-9y^2+6y-1=0.$$

Therefore $(xyz)^2=\frac{1}{3}$ and hence $xyz=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$.

In addition I think this may be one of the simplest direct solutions:

Adding the equations: $$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=0=>xy+yz+zx=0.$$ Clearing the denominators of the original equations ($x^2-xy-1=0, \dots$) and adding we obtain $$x^2+y^2+z^2=xy+yz+zx+3=3$$ Hence $$(x+y+z)^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+yz+zx)=3=>(x+y+z)=\pm\sqrt{3}$$Rearranging the original equations ($y+\frac{1}{x}=x,\dots$), multiplying them and simplifying: $$(y+\frac{1}{x})(z+\frac{1}{y})(x+\frac{1}{z})=xyz =>(x+y+z)=-\frac{1}{xyz}.$$ Combining we obtain the result $$xyz=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}.$$

Comment: You can only deduce $(xyz)^2=\frac13$ if $x^2,y^2,z^2$ are _distinct_ roots of the cubic. This is not difficult to show, from the original equations, but it has to be done for a complete proof.

Comment: But how can I proceed through solution using the method I provided in the question(image link). I am unable to understand the steps after 'add all'. how are we getting zero after that?

Comment: @ShubhamKumarVerma: I would say that is not Ivan's problem!

Comment: @TonyK Subtle, but fair point! In this case as you say it's trivial to see that x=y is not possible, similarly for the other equalities.

Comment: @Ivan: Not _quite_ so simple. You must also rule out $y=-x$ etc.